# Vector definition of two lines with only the parameters differing

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

A question says,

> If $\vec r =\vec a + \lambda \vec b$ and $\vec r= \vec p + \mu\vec d$ be two lines such that $\vec b =t\vec d$ and $\vec a -\vec p = s\vec b$, where $\lambda, \mu, t, $and $s$ be non-zero scalars, do the two lines have a unique point of intersection?

I simplified the line equations to these; $$\vec r = \vec p + t(s+\lambda)\vec d \\ \vec r = \vec p + \mu \vec d$$
Now, the book solution says these are parallel lines(so the answer to the question's no).

Assuming the book meant the 'non-zero scalars' to also mean the parameters for the lines, wouldn't the lines be coincident? The question specifies *lines*, so these lines stretch infinitely in either direction; this implies the effective(I mean consider the mess in the first equation as just one parameter)parameters to both equations would need to have all real values. Which also tells me both lines coincide.

Where did I go wrong in my reasoning?,

Comment: I think the two lines are indeed coincident (so, they are also parallel), except at P, since the second line has a puncture at P.

Comment: @Ryan G: Oh, yeah, there's a hole, thanks. So I guess the book was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the book is correct, since the two lines

1. are indeed parallel, since they are coincident except at P (where the second line has a puncture but not the first);
2. have no unique intersection point.

Comment: Right- the book just said parallel, which also encompasses coincidence, so it works both ways, except at P. Is that right?

Comment: @HarryHolmes 1. Since parallelism (unlike coincidence) is a property of lines, planes, etc. but not points, the puncture doesn’t diminish the fact that the two lines are parallel, so I’d simply say that they are parallel (with no qualification). 2. Coincident lines are necessarily parallel, but not vice versa..